# fused location provider provides fake accurate location

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

I'm using the fused location provider to track the user location on android. Most of the time it works great, the location signals seem correct, but from time to time I receive fake location points which seem accurate (accuracy <= 30) from a distant point which I have never visited. It happens to other people in my floor, who use different android devices and different cell providers. All of us "jump" to the same location point from time to time, and after a while we come back to our true location.
Did anyone experience this issue?
I don't know how to tell which signals are real and which aren't. I suspect that it is the WIFI provider which provides the fake signals from time to time (since we are inside a building and the signals are accurate), but I'm not sure. 
Can I extract provider's data from the fused location provider? I want to know which provider provided the fake signals

Thanks,
Li